# What means the Error-Code 520 in IBM Notes?

Tags: ibm-cloud, lotus-notes, lotus

I permanently get the "Notes Error 520". I get no additional (Debug-) Information from IBM Notes.

Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

I´m using IBM Notes IBM Notes 9 Social Edition Release 9.0.1FP6 Revision 20160423.1936-FP6 (Release 9.0.1FP6)

Screenshot --> [Notes Error 520](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY0kD.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @ThomasAdrian  Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY0kD.png

Comment: What is taskeng? Are you just using Notes client or are you developing something?

Comment: @ThomasAdrian I don´t know what taskeng exactly do, but its a Windows Executable for scheduling something.
 I´m using the Notes client und don´t develop something.

Comment: TaskEng is from the Windows Task Scheduler Engine. Do you have some tasks with Notes scheduled ?

Comment: @umeli As far as i know is nothing scheduled.

Comment: @ThomasAdrian Any news?

Comment: I think you need to provide some kind of scenario when this happen. is it when you login to Notes or is it when you open an database etc.  your screenshot doesn't show the Notes client at all.

Comment: @ThomasAdrian It just so happens when I'm working in Notes, when I've minimized Notes and continue working in other programs. There is no scheme or pattern when the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Error 520 is a user-defined error code.  What you're probably seeing is the developer's lazy error handling where it just does a

```
msgbox "Error: " + cstr(err)
```

What 520 means is that we would have no way of knowing what the error is without seeing the code that's running.  Your best bet is to contact the developer and ask him/her.